# Unfortunately example app has stopped android emulator

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I tried to run my app but I got a message "Unfortunately app has stopped" when I do the process in error logcat there error Fatal Exception Asynctask #1 why? any solution for me?

here is a full logcat

```
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at com.example.example.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:125)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at com.example.example.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-30 09:15:30.957: E/AndroidRuntime(580):  ... 5 more
```

Login.java

```
package com.example.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText user, pass;
private Button mSubmit, mRegister;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/android/login.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.login);

user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.login:
    new AttemptLogin().execute();
    break;
case R.id.register:
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;

default:
    break;
}
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... v) {

    int success;
    String username = user.getText().toString();
    String password = pass.getText().toString();
    try {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        Log.d("request!", "starting");

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                params);

        Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());


        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

            SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
            Editor edit = sp.edit();
            edit.putString("username", username);
            edit.commit();

            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComment.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(i);
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
            return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

    pDialog.dismiss();
    if (file_url != null) {
        Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

}

}
```

Comment: Please add the code, and point to the line, where the NPE happens.

Comment: what should I change ? I didn't understand after all , because I'm new in android please

Comment: which line is line 125?

Comment: maybe this 
Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Comment: Well, looks like json is null.

Comment: and then Which code should I change?

Answer (score 2):

You get a `NullPointerException` in line 125 of file `Login.java`. Go to your code and try to determine how a value can be null in this line in the code.

How do I know this?

The trace contains this code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
...  at com.example.example.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:125)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, void, String>
```

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation.

Comment: still the same nothing happened

Comment: Make sure you recieve a json that is not null..
Edit this "http://10.0.2.2/android/login.php" .. change POST to GET in that file and echo the resulting json
Using your browser.. goto
http://10.0.2.2/android/login.php/username=blah&password=blah
Make sure there is something returned @LuhungHaryo